# javascript error "TypeError: html.match is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking for someone who can guide me how to get special tag from string-formated html.

Comment: Where is `HTML(...)` from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Cristian Traina.  I updated the code. it was html.match(linkRx)

Comment: If match is not a function, html is not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the method `match` on your variable `html` does not exist, hence that it's most probably not a string.

You can either verify that the type of your `html` variable is indeed a string (using `typeof` for instance), or manually cast it into a string using the [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor